# OutOfMemoryException while extracting OBJ

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a Revit file and I am trying to extract geometry of it (OBJ file)(master view activated as I need space volumes)

I am calling GetDerivativeManifestAsync method from DerivativesApi class from Autodesk.Forge

`await derivative.GetDerivativeManifestAsync(urn, derivativeUrn);`

However I am getting System.OutOfMemoryException thrown from forge client.

`Reason: Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException: Error calling GetDerivativeManifest: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

Why does it happen and how can I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might mean that the OBJ file is too large for your computer to handle. Please use this API of Forge Dotnet SDK to check the file size:

```
IDictionary<string, string> headers = derivative.GetDerivativeManifestHeaders(urn, derivativeUrn);

long fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(headers["Content-Length"]);
            
Console.WriteLine ("\t size: " + fileSize); //!<<< in bytes
```

Comment: Downloading the file in chunks helped